# Is it okay to BULD UP to praying all 5 prayers?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices, prayer-timings

I am new to Islam and have been trying to get my wife and I to pray more and better.

Seeing as we almost never pray, I decided to make a plan to help us achieve all 5 prayers a day in a way that would teach us habitually and progressively.

To start, we will pray at least once a day at Isha for a month.
Then add another prayer time for the next month.
Than, Do that 3 more times until we are finally doing all 5.

Unfortunately, she hates the idea saying, “praying once a day is worse than not praying at all, either we pray all 5 from the beginning or we don’t pray at all” the problem is I know us! I know we will not be able to keep it up and quit very soon after starting. My method would help us gradually cut the times in our schedules to pray every single day without being overwhelmed and stressed. We would be able to ensure each prayer a spot in the day; 1 by 1 until there is no excuse for not praying and also gradually build and habbitualize our prayer times so there is 0 reasons as to why we didn’t pray.

I understand praying once a day isn’t good but taking the long way around to ensure and solidify all of the prayers one by one is SO much better than…
going in blind getting stressed, not planning, accidentally missing a prayer, getting lazy, forgetting and finding excuses to not pray.

Am I wrong? How should we start praying again so that we can keep doing it?

Comment: It is not 'okay' because praying all 5 prayers is obligatory. But praying one is better than not praying any and so on.

Comment: It is okay, from the life of the Prophet Muhammad SAW, many new tribes and convert came and he allowed themselves to ease into the obligations by starting with 2 prayers a day as told in 1 event during the Life of the Prophet.

Answer (score -1):

Motivate yourself and her by reading the various ahadith pertaining to the rewards of establishing salaah and the severe, tormenting punishments of discarding it.